# is real time data syncing possible with redux, in multiple devices?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

suppose there 2 computer systems in an office. and they have a common web application running on both the systems. one computer system is alloted to the employee and another computer system is alloted to the  admin. when employee logins, his schedule is visible to him on his dashboard. when admin logins, all the employee's schedule is visible on his dashboard. now lets assume that because of some event or reason, the admin need to change/update the schedule of the employee. so when the admin makes this change to schedule of the employee who is currently logged in on the other system, this change in schedule must reflect immediately on the employee dashboard in his schedule.

so how to achieve this. in other words how will the schedule component in the employee's dashboard know that there has been some new update in the schedule data.

remember that i am talking in terms of a react js web application

can this be solved by using only redux ? since there are 2 computer systems involved, i have doubt over redux ?

if it is not possbile with redux, then tell me what else i can use ?

Answer (score 0):

Redux stores the state locally. You can use WebSocket. Define a parameter that will change when the data changes and refetch the data.